# setState of multiple objects - React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push, setstate

I'm having problems when I want to update the state of an array and I am using the push() method to add the new values ​​but apparently push does not update, so I have doubts if I can make a setState of multiple values.

Here's the code with the push() method:

```
buildDetailDB = () => {
    let {detail} = this.state;
    //console.log(detail)
    let dms=[];
    detail.dms.map(fabric => {
      dms.push({
        "line_id": fabric.line_id,
        "id": fabric.id,
        "dm": fabric.dm,
        "priceWhite": fabric.priceWhite,
        "priceMedium": fabric.priceMedium,
        "priceDark": fabric.priceDark,
        "priceSpecial": fabric.priceSpecial,
        "priceWhiteC": 0,
        "priceMediumC": 0,
        "priceDarkC": 0,
        "priceSpecialC": 0,
        "Blong": this.FixElementValue(fabric.Blong),
        "Bwidth": this.FixElementValue(fabric.Bwidth),
        "fabricType": fabric.fabricType,
        "weightBWashOriginal": this.FixElementValue(fabric.weightBWashOriginal),
        "weightBWashCalculated": this.FixElementValue(fabric.weightBWashCalculated),
        "dm_width": this.FixElementValue(fabric.dm_width),
        "markerWidth": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerWidth),
        "dm_pt": fabric.dm_pt,
        "yieldydslbs": this.FixElementValue(fabric.yieldydslbs),
        "markerEfficiency": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerEfficiency),
        "markerLong": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerLong),
        "pieceByMarker": this.FixElementValue(fabric.pieceByMarker),
        "lbsunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunit),
        "lbsunitwaste": this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunitwaste),
        "sqinchunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.sqinchunit),
        "ydsunit": fabric.ydsunit,
        "bydspunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.bydspunit),
        "blbspunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.blbspunit),
      })
      console.log(fabric)
      return fabric;
    });
```

Comment: `push` modifies state directly. It's also odd that you're `map`ping and ignoring the result; build the DM and return it--that's what `map` is *for*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what the rest of your `detail` state looks like but I'm assuming it's an array of objects. Instead of destructuring your `detail` from state and performing updates that way, you can utilize the `prevState` callback that `setState()` offers.

The following below should pretty much get you there.

```
buildDetailDB = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    detail: [
      ...prevState.detail,
      {
        dms: prevState.detail.dms.map((fabric) => ({
          line_id: fabric.line_id,
          id: fabric.id,
          dm: fabric.dm,
          priceWhite: fabric.priceWhite,
          priceMedium: fabric.priceMedium,
          priceDark: fabric.priceDark,
          priceSpecial: fabric.priceSpecial,
          priceWhiteC: 0,
          priceMediumC: 0,
          priceDarkC: 0,
          priceSpecialC: 0,
          Blong: this.FixElementValue(fabric.Blong),
          Bwidth: this.FixElementValue(fabric.Bwidth),
          fabricType: fabric.fabricType,
          weightBWashOriginal: this.FixElementValue(fabric.weightBWashOriginal),
          weightBWashCalculated: this.FixElementValue(
            fabric.weightBWashCalculated
          ),
          dm_width: this.FixElementValue(fabric.dm_width),
          markerWidth: this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerWidth),
          dm_pt: fabric.dm_pt,
          yieldydslbs: this.FixElementValue(fabric.yieldydslbs),
          markerEfficiency: this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerEfficiency),
          markerLong: this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerLong),
          pieceByMarker: this.FixElementValue(fabric.pieceByMarker),
          lbsunit: this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunit),
          lbsunitwaste: this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunitwaste),
          sqinchunit: this.FixElementValue(fabric.sqinchunit),
          ydsunit: fabric.ydsunit,
          bydspunit: this.FixElementValue(fabric.bydspunit),
          blbspunit: this.FixElementValue(fabric.blbspunit),
        })),
      },
    ],
  }));
};
```

@eduardorh1312 Added that prevState callback parameter.

Comment: where did you initialize the prevstate?, it throws me an non existing error

Comment: Apologies, missed adding that callback parameter. Check my edit for the working version.

Answer (score 0):

Or another way would be to just do what you did and set the state at the end of pushing

```
buildDetailDB = () => {
let {detail} = this.state;
//console.log(detail)
let dms=[];
detail.dms.forEach(fabric => {
  dms.push({
    "line_id": fabric.line_id,
    "id": fabric.id,
    "dm": fabric.dm,
    "priceWhite": fabric.priceWhite,
    "priceMedium": fabric.priceMedium,
    "priceDark": fabric.priceDark,
    "priceSpecial": fabric.priceSpecial,
    "priceWhiteC": 0,
    "priceMediumC": 0,
    "priceDarkC": 0,
    "priceSpecialC": 0,
    "Blong": this.FixElementValue(fabric.Blong),
    "Bwidth": this.FixElementValue(fabric.Bwidth),
    "fabricType": fabric.fabricType,
    "weightBWashOriginal": this.FixElementValue(fabric.weightBWashOriginal),
    "weightBWashCalculated": this.FixElementValue(fabric.weightBWashCalculated),
    "dm_width": this.FixElementValue(fabric.dm_width),
    "markerWidth": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerWidth),
    "dm_pt": fabric.dm_pt,
    "yieldydslbs": this.FixElementValue(fabric.yieldydslbs),
    "markerEfficiency": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerEfficiency),
    "markerLong": this.FixElementValue(fabric.markerLong),
    "pieceByMarker": this.FixElementValue(fabric.pieceByMarker),
    "lbsunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunit),
    "lbsunitwaste": this.FixElementValue(fabric.lbsunitwaste),
    "sqinchunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.sqinchunit),
    "ydsunit": fabric.ydsunit,
    "bydspunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.bydspunit),
    "blbspunit": this.FixElementValue(fabric.blbspunit),
  })
  this.setState({detail: {...detail, dms}})
});
```